# How to store a list in the web sql or any type of storage in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-sql, web-storage

How to store a list in the web sql or any type of storage in the browser,
I have found three ways to store data in the browser, i.e. localstorage,session storage and web sql with html5 so i need to store the java.util.List in the browser and need to modify it at in future so is there any way to do so?

Comment: It seems like a strange need, what are you trying to accomplish? There might a better overall solution?

Comment: You do not store raw Java objects in the browser. You convert it to some suitable format, usually JSON, XML or some other raw text format, and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, we need to first take the list in local var in the page and than through javascript iterate it and store in the local browser db.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure - you need to store and manipulate the 'List' on the server or on the client?

In the first case you may use session. In second case you can't use session because you can not access session variables in javascript.

In such situation I'm usually creating hidden field (if it's something page related) or cookie (if it's something application related). Using base64 you may pass transformed to string List to the client, modify them and save. Of course later you may read the data on the server.